# Searching a 2D grid in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, 2d

Please take a look: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-a-word-in-a-2d-grid-of-characters/

This is a C++ program that searches  a 2D grid for a particular word.

In, the code, there are two declarations:

```
int x[]={-1,-1,-1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1};
int y[]={-1, 0, 1,-1, 1,-1, 0, 1};
```

Can anyone please explain these?? The author says these are for searching in all the 8 directions. But i am not getting how??

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code, my interpretation is that the 8 directions are given by

```
x     y
-1    -1     left down
-1    0      left
-1    1      left up
 0    -1     down
etc.
```

and thats what is encoded in this two arrays. Now if you have two coordinates:

```
int xx,yy;
```

you can get all neighbouring coordinates in a loop:

```
for (int i=0;i<8;i++) {
    nx = xx + x[i];
    ny = yy + y[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would be waaaaay easier to read had this been described as pairs: `{{-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, -1}, {0, 1}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}`. This is what you'll add to the coordinates. First is `x`, second is `y`. The eight directions are NW, N, NE, W, E, SW, S, SE, these are listed as diff. of coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

So there are 8 directions you can go in to check the surrounding letters in the matrix. Imagine this:

```
NW - N - NE
 |   |   |
 W -curr-E
 |   |   |
SW   S   SE
```

Those are the 8 directions (northwest, down to southeast), sorry for the ugly drawing. But the numbers used in the x[] and y[] just allow you to navigate up 1, down 1, or stay the same for the x and y coordinate in the matrix.